# Making `group by` result in multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a (`Postgres`) query with a usual `group by` clause:

```
select extract(year from a.created) as Year,a.testscoreid, b.irt_tlevel, count(a.*) as Questions
from asmt.testscores a join asmt.questions b
on a.questionid = b.questionid
where a.answered = True
group by Year,a.testscoreid, b.irt_tlevel
order by Year desc, a.testscoreid
```

The column `b.irt_tlevel` has values `low`, `medium` and `high`, all these results are in a row-format, for example:

```
Year    TestScoreId    Irt_tlevel    Questions
2015    1              Low           2
2015    1              Medium        3
2015    1              High          5
```

I'd like my results to be in the following format:

```
Year    TestScoreId    Low    Medium    High    TotalQuestions
2015    1              2      3         5        10
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The correct way is using [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation if it is known that the number of distinct values in irt_tlevel column are fixed.

```
select 
extract(year from a.created) as Year,
a.testscoreid, 
sum(case when b.irt_tlevel = 'Low' then 1 else 0 end) as Low,
sum(case when b.irt_tlevel = 'Medium' then 1 else 0 end) as Medium,
sum(case when b.irt_tlevel = 'High' then 1 else 0 end) as High,
count(*) as Questions
from asmt.testscores a 
join asmt.questions b on a.questionid = b.questionid
where a.answered = True
group by Year, a.testscoreid
order by Year desc, a.testscoreid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    extract(year from a.created) as Year,
    a.testscoreid,
    b.irt_tlevel,
    count(Irt_tlevel = 'low' or null) as "Low",
    count(Irt_tlevel = 'medium' or null) as "Medium",
    count(Irt_tlevel = 'high' or null) as "High",
    count(a.*) as "TotalQuestions"
from
    asmt.testscores a
    join
    asmt.questions b on a.questionid = b.questionid
where a.answered
group by Year, a.testscoreid
order by Year desc, a.testscoreid
```

Comment: count(col1 = col2) is MySQL syntax, but the question is for PostgreSQL. Nitpick: in MySQL, if you use `sum(col1 = col2)`, you don't need the `or null`

Comment: @Andomar This is fine in PostgreSQL. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91f69/1/0). What's going on is that `Irt_tlevel = 'low'` is a boolean condition. `false OR NULL` is `NULL` (since the value cannot be known). `true OR NULL` is `true` (since the second value is irrelevant). `COUNT` only counts non-`NULL` items (as per SQL standard, and other DBs do follow the standard here). So the `OR NULL` just converts `false` to `NULL` so that the `COUNT` only counts rows where the condition is `true`. There's no special syntax here; it's just normal expressions being fed into an aggregate fucntion.

Comment: @jpmc26: Cool, thanks for clearing that up. I assumed Postgres required a `case` to evaluate expressions like SQL Server does

Comment: @Andomar One of the things that, imo, sets PostgreSQL apart is that it shies away from special syntax rules like that. It has a dedicate boolean type that you can use anywhere, and as long as your expression evaluates to the type needed, chances are you can just plop any form of it in there. (I've run into limitations with mixing aggregate functions, but that's usually solved by a subquery.) I find those limitations maddening on other DBs, like having to have `CASE` statements all over the place to spit out `'Y'` and `'N'` characters since I can't just use a real boolean in Oracle.