# postgres sql query to convert group by result in multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, pivot, where-clause

I have two tables

1. financial_account having columns account_name
2. financial_transaction having columns transaction_date,transaction_type, transaction_amount

I need data as SUM(transaction_amount) where transaction_type='A' under column SUM_A and SUM(transaction_amount) under column SUM_B where transaction_type='B'

I took reference of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500598/making-group-by-result-in-multiple-columns) stackoverflow post , wrote query as below :

```
select fa.account_name ,
to_char(current_date - interval '1' month, 'Mon-YY') as "Previous Month",
SUM(case when ft.transaction_type='A' then ft.transaction_amount else 0 end) as "SUM_A",
SUM(case when ft.transaction_type='B' then ft.transaction_amount else 0 end) as "SUM_B"

from financial_transaction ft

join financial_account fa on fa.account_name = 'XYZ'

where ft.transaction_date  >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month' and
      ft.transaction_date  < date_trunc('month', now())

group by ft.transaction_type,fa.account_name

having ft.transaction_type in ('A','B')
```

However, this query is generating data in two rows

[image]

I needed data in single row format.

[image]

**How can i get data in 1 one row format?**

Comment: In group by clause replace `group by ft.transaction_type,fa.account_name` with `group by 1,2` and move `ft.transaction_type in ('A','B')` in where clause. It seems you have 2 different transaction_type

Comment: Your join condition is wrong. Should be `on ft.account_name = fa.account_name`.  The query will become more readable if you use `SUM(ft.transaction_amount) filter (where ft.transaction_type = 'A') as "SUM_A"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your query is working properly, you can write your query like below:

```
select 
fa.account_name ,
to_char(current_date - interval '1' month, 'Mon-YY') as "Previous Month",
SUM(case when ft.transaction_type='A' then ft.transaction_amount else 0 end) as "SUM_A",
SUM(case when ft.transaction_type='B' then ft.transaction_amount else 0 end) as "SUM_B"
from financial_transaction ft
join financial_account fa on fa.account_name = 'XYZ'
where ft.transaction_date  >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month' and
      ft.transaction_date  < date_trunc('month', now()) and ft.transaction_type in ('A','B')

group by 1,2
```

You can write it like below also:

```
select 
fa.account_name ,
to_char(current_date - interval '1' month, 'Mon-YY') as "Previous Month",
SUM(ft.transaction_amount) filter (where ft.transaction_type='A') as "SUM_A",
SUM(ft.transaction_amount) filter (where ft.transaction_type='B') as "SUM_B",
from financial_transaction ft
join financial_account fa on fa.account_name = 'XYZ'
where ft.transaction_date  >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month' and
      ft.transaction_date  < date_trunc('month', now()) and ft.transaction_type in ('A','B')
group by 1,2
```

Comment: both the solution worked. what does group by 1,2 suggest?

Comment: In `Group by 1, 2` 1 and 2 represent first and second column of your select. i.e. 1 means `fa.account_name`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to remove `ft.transaction_type` from the `group by` clause, so all rows of the same account are grouped together.

Let me pinpoint that your query seems to be missing a join condition between the transactions and accounts.

I would write the query as:

```
select 
    fa.account_name,
    trunc(current_date - interval '1' month) as previous_month,
    sum(ft.transaction_amount) filter(where ft.transaction_type = 'A') as sum_a,
    sum(ft.transaction_amount) filter(where ft.transaction_type = 'B') as sum_b
from financial_transaction ft
inner join financial_account fa on ??
where 
    fa.account_name = 'XYZ'
    and ft.transaction_date  >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month' 
    and ft.transaction_date  < date_trunc('month', current_date)
    and ft.transaction_type in ('A','B')
group by fa.account_name
```

Changes to your original code:

- Fixed the `group by` clause
- I represented that missing join condition as `??`.
- The condition on the transaction type should belong to the `where` clause rather than the `having` clause
- The conditional sums can be simplified with the standard `filter` clause